# How to get column widths of 600 and 300 pixels in bootstrap3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, less

I'm trying to compile my own bootstrap3 template, and change variables defined in variables.less to get 2 sizes of columns, main column with 600px and sidebar column with 300px (without paddings/margins).

I've tried different combinations for number of columns, but can't get exact sizes. 
For example, with 12 columns and 30px gutter, and total width of 960px, combination of 4 columns gives me 300 pixels, but 8 columns combined is 630px.

I need exact combination of values where gutter can be between 30 and 40 pixels, container width between 940 and 980. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, had to write a script to calculate all possible combinations..

And here are results that match my requirements:

container width: 940px

columns: 49

gutter: 40px

As a result, I can combine 17 columns to get 300px, and 32 columns to get 600px.

That is it, maybe it will be helpful to someone else too.